# PHP File download interferes with AJAX Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I have embedded a Wordpress Gravity Form on a page. After submission, I fetch an ACF file and download it via a hook like so.

```
function masterstart_brochure_download() {
    $file = get_field('brochure_file');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . 
    basename($file['url']) . "\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Length: " . $file['sizes']['thumbnail']);
    header("Connection: close");

    exit();
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_21', 'masterstart_brochure_download', 10, 2 );
```

The Gravity form submits via AJAX. Once the form submits I'm opening a modal thanking the user for submitting the form.

```
/* After Form Submission */
$(document).on("gform_confirmation_loaded", function (e, form_id) {
    // If the brochure download form is submitted
    if(form_id == 21) {
        var brochureModal = $('[data-remodal-id=brochure-
        download]').remodal();
        brochureModal.open();
    }
});
```

The above Wordpress hook downloads the file correctly but prevents the AJAX call from finishing and successfully submitting the form.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**UPDATE 1:**
I thought adding

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

might help but to no avail.

Comment: So just to be clear, your Gravity form submits via AJAX, the page it submits to then runs masterstart_brochure_download(), returning a file to download, then it's not continuing with the JS after the file download/AJAX returns?

Comment: @JamesHunt yes. correct.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is that your AJAX file returns a file to download and your JS doesn't continue afterwards.

This is because AJAX cannot strictly be used to download files, so if you check your Network tab on the Inspector you'll see the file doesn't return correctly (in Firefox it doesn't even return a status code!)

If the AJAX call never ends, it's never successful or a failure, so no callbacks!

You could always use an iFrame to trigger the download, or a pop-up window.